# Generating confirmation url in custom devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mandrill

I am using the Mandrill API to handle my transactional email for a variety of reasons. One issue I am encountering is generating the confirmation_url, edit_password_url and unlock_url in the new mailer. I am including Devise's URL helpers in the new mailer. Everything else in the email is being generated properly.

I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `main_app' for #<DeviseMailer:0x007f812b6abe78>):
  app/mailers/devise_mailer.rb:15:in `confirmation_instructions'
  app/controllers/lenders/registrations_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

**devise_mailer.rb**

```
class DeviseMailer < MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers

  default from: 'no-reply@test.com'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token)
    mandrill_mail template: 'Confirmation Instructions',
                  subject:  'Confirm Email',
                  from_name: 'Test',
                  to: { email: record.email },
                  vars: {
                    'FNAME'                  => record.first_name,
                    'LIST_COMPANY'           => "Apples",
                    'HTML_LIST_ADDRESS_HTML' => "1 Infinite Loop",
                    'CONFIRMATION_LINK'      => confirmation_url(record, :confirmation_token => token)
                  }
  end
end
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone hitting this issue - I had the same method missing issue when using [mandrill_mailer](https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer) to replace devise's customer mailer.

Using the above example above I fixed it like so

```
class DeviseMailer < MandrillMailer::TemplateMaile

    # ..... mailer code in here here .....

    private

    def main_app
      Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    end

end
```